# AWS CodeDeploy + Codeship Deployment Failed

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-code-deploy

Aws CodeDeploy issue: .zip file is going to s3 images, deployments starts and get failed and the error Status is just `failed` earlier it was showing error in hooks `ApplicationStart` but i went to instance and setup the node enviroment manually, now this error is not coming but `deployment fails" with status`failed`no further details of logs, and it is not able to fetch`.zip`file from`s3`to my`instance`and i don't know why it is not taking the files directly from github even  i have set up codeDeploy in such a manner to`connect my github`.

Comment: I think we need a lot more info about what you are doing. Can you provide more details or code samples?